# How to restart paused workflow automatically when the item is modified

Tags: designer-workflow

I have date column(Expiry Date), based on Expiry Date users need to get email notifications on (-15 days of Expiry Date,on Expiry Date,+15 Days of Expiry Date).
User don't get emails if suppose they have updated after (-15 days of Expiry Date)email and restart the workflow and set the Expiry Date to current updated date(new Expiry Date) and get emails based on current Expiry Date.
It's like renewal process.

Can you please suggest how to restart the paused workflow immediately when an item has changed and trigger the workflow for new Expiry Date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,

can anyone look into the issue and could provide suggestions to get it resolve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend you to use a Retention workflow instead of a pause workflow for this to run 15 days after modified date

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a Retention workflow instead of a pause workflow for this to run 15 days after modified date.

for this you require a SharePoint 2010 workflow and modify the "Information management policy settings" in the list you want to modify,

select the content type of the items to be modified and add a retention workflow.

over there you'll see the options of when the workflow is going to start, and the action" Run a 2010 workflow.

Comment: Here we are using SharePoint 2013 on premises, and SharePoint 2013 workflow platform.

Comment: this is all available in sharepoint 2013 on premises